# Replace multiline text between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

I need to replace `old` value between `foo{` and `}bar` using Javascript regex.

```
foo{old}bar
```

This works if `old` is a single line:

```
replace(
    /(foo{).*(}bar)/,
    '$1' + 'new' + '$2'
)
```

I need to make it work with:

```
foo{old value
which takes more
than one line}bar
```

How should I change my regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
/(foo{)[^{}]*(}bar)/
```

OR

```
/(foo{)[\s\S]*?(}bar)/
```

so that it would match also a newline character. `[^{}]*` matches any character but not of `{` or `}`, zero or more times. `[\s\S]*?` matches any space or non-space characters, zero or more times non-greedily.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I'll accept it as soon as it will be possible. :)